# How to set root term in Hirerchical select

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms

I have a vocabulary like the following:

Parent 1
  Child 1
  Child 2

Parent 2
  Child 3
  Child 4

I want the dropdown only to show Parent 2 and its childs, so I changed the root_term id to parent id

'root_term' => termid, // Enter a term ID here if you want to display only terms below the term with that ID.

function mymodule_alter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

```
if($form_id == 'myform_node_form')
{    
  $form['field_myfield']['und']['#config']['params']['root_term']= termid;
}
```

Please let me know how to achieve this ??

Comment: i found the solution http://drupal.org/node/263365#comment-6107218 hope this helps Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in [this link](http://drupal.org/node/263365#comment-6107218) ,this is bug in `HS` module.

finally i found your mistake
in your code , in hs_taxonomy.module 
in function hs_taxonomy_hierarchical_select_root_level($params) you don't consider
$params['root_term'] and in every hs this item bypassed by 0 value

```
<?php
$terms = _hs_taxonomy_hierarchical_select_get_tree($params['vid'], 0, -1, 1);
?>
```

must be

```
<?php
$terms = _hs_taxonomy_hierarchical_select_get_tree($params['vid'], $params['root_term'], -1, 1);
?>
```

if user not set parent in content_taxonomy settings for term reference it passed 0 by default.

please apply this patch to your module.
just notice for this work correctly you want select (not duplicate second level select option)
Save term lineage 
in Hierarchical Select configuration in Save lineage part.
i test it ,working like a 'BENZ'